# Updating cells from external workbook with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim ExternalWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ExternalWorksheet As Worksheet

' Get the file path from cell A1
FilePath = Range("A1").Value

' Activate the worksheet where you want to update cells
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

' Open the external workbook
Set ExternalWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

' Set the external worksheet to retrieve data from
Set ExternalWorksheet = ExternalWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Update cells in the current worksheet with data from the external worksheet
Range("D5:W5").Value = ExternalWorksheet.Range("D5:W5").Value

' Close the external workbook without saving changes
ExternalWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

' Notify the user that the update is complete
MsgBox "Cells updated successfully!"
```

End Sub

I have a cashflow of aprox 20 months in both the workbook/sheet I want to pull the info from, and in the workbook/sheet i am running the macro from. The cashflows are in the same location (D5:W5). The code seems to open the file, as i see it flicker momentarily, then I receive the successful update message, but the cells are not updating.

I have tried everything, but just cannot seem to get it to work

Comment: `Range("D5:W5").Value = ExternalWorksheet.Range("D5:W5").Value` ---> `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5:W5").Value = ExternalWorksheet.Range("D5:W5").Value`. Good practice is to qualify the workbook and worksheet for any `Range` or `Cells` or `Rows` or `Columns` calls.

Comment: Thanks BigBen! This works! How would I edit this if I renamed the external worksheet range to CF and wanted to pull it out based on its named range

Comment: `ExternalWorksheet.Range("CF")` I believe.

Comment: That works too. Legend. Why didn't my original code work?

Comment: You're implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, which is the sheet in the external workbook. Your code overwrites the values in the external workbook.

Comment: You wrote : _Update cells in the **current worksheet** .._ -->after your open workbook line, the bold words means "whatever active sheet of the ExternalWorkbook". Compare with this : _Update cells in **sheet1 of the workbook where this sub reside** .._ then you need to write the code as Mr. BigBen suggestion.